# Vue.js custom component can't find img src

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, src

So I am trying to make a custom component that inserts a icon.svg from a specific directory in my assets. The component loads in fine and custom attributes work too, however when they try to look for the image I get a 404 error.

[image]
[image]

[image]

```html
    <template>
  <img :src="'../src/assets/heroicons/'+this.styling+'/'+this.icon+'.svg'" alt=""> <!-- this one does not work -->
  <img src="../src/assets/heroicons/solid/database.svg" alt=""> <!-- this one works -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "IconComp",
  props: [
    'styling',
      'icon'
  ],
  created() {
    console.log(this.styling+' '+this.icon)
  }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
  img {
    filter: invert(100%);
  }
</style>
```

As you can see in the images, the attributes end up at the right place but it can't find the files.

Comment: the rendered attributes are *not* pointing to the right place. /src/ isn't a directory the browser should be able to access

Comment: `:src="require('../src/assets/heroicons/'+this.styling+'/'+this.icon+'.svg')`"

Comment: For assets you will have to place them in the `public` folder. Even if it works locally, it may not work on production.

Answer (score 0):

I use images in vue:

```
  <template>
    <img class="avatar__img" src="src/assets/img/task.png" alt="profile avatar">
    or
    <img class="task__img" :src="task.img" :alt="task.alt">
  </template>

  <script>
    const task = {
         alt: 'alt for task 1',
        img: 'src/assets/img/task.png',
    }
  </script>
```

**img path**: projectName/src/assets/img/task.png 
**component**: projectName/src/pages/tasks/index.vue

Answer (score 0):

use a js object to record the icons info

```js
export default {
    icon1: require('@/assets/.......'),
    icon2: require('@/assets/.......'),
    icon3: require('@/assets/.......'),
    icon4: require('@/assets/.......'),
}
```

then you can use these icons in your code everywhere