# Concatenate property and string for an image source

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to display an image based on the concatenation of a fixed path and a property.
Do you know how I can do that?

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: String
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <img src="@/assets/covers/{{id}}.jpg" width="240" height="180" />
  <img src="'@/assets/covers/' + id + '.jpg'" width="240" height="180" />
  <img src="`@/assets/covers/${id}.jpg`" width="240" height="180" />
  <h1>@/assets/covers/{{id}}.jpg</h1>
</template>
```

I tried these 3 solutions but none are working. The h1 is displaying what I want though.

I even tried this:

```
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    id: String
  },
  data() {
    return {
      url: "@/assets/covers/" + this.id + ".jpg"
    }
  }
}
</script>

<template>
  <img src="@/assets/covers/title.jpg" width="240" height="180" />
  <img src=url width="240" height="180" />
  <h1>@/assets/covers/title.jpg</h1>
  <h1>{{url}}</h1>
</template>
```

The two h1 displays the exact same text, but only the first image is showing, not the second one.

Comment: Remove the img tags you have except the last one, and add before the `src` the `:`. At the end it should looks like this: `<img :src="`@/assets/covers/${id}.jpg`" width="240" height="180" />`. Also if I am not wrong, the `@` at the front of the image will not work for your case. You have to move the images in the `public` folder and remove the `@` from the dynamic image URLs.

Comment: It doesn't work, I get this error: Error parsing JavaScript expression: Unexpected token, expected "," (1:16)
On this line: <img :src="public/covers/${id}.jpg" width="240" height="180" />

Comment: You need to use a template literal: `:src="\`@/assets/covers/${id}.jpg\`"`

Comment: @MichałSadowski I already tried that, see the first code block, it didn't work.

Comment: You still lacked the `:`

Comment: @MichałSadowski Yes, I also tried with them, it doesn't work either.

Comment: how does the rendered HTML look like?

Comment: @MichałSadowski You mean this?
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/@vite/client"></script>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>***</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script type="module" src="/src/main.js?t=1669815102960"></script>
  </body>
</html>

Comment: I mean already rendered in the browser, the part with imgs

Comment: @MichałSadowski The images is like this: <img src="@/assets/covers/atomichabits.jpg" width="240" height="180">
So it seems like the @ isn't correctly replaced, but when I replace it with "/src" it works :)

Answer (score 0):

Here I've described how to use images in vue3. Probably it could help you.

[how to use img in vue3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74621812/20639512)